# Video controls not clickable

Tags: video

I am getting closer to my goal, but there's a few small issues with my website (mostly the video and the header) that I cannot figure out.

I was finally able to get the video to display in the header like I wanted, but now the controls don't work. Ultimately, the only control I'm interested in is the mute. I would like the video to be automatically muted, but the user have the ability to unmute if they would like.

Here is my site:https://www.enjoywithgusto.com/

here is my code:
`<video class="vjs-tech" id="uploadplayer-player-1582250741916_html5_api" poster="/uploads/b/10433641-458365002498822034/final_v1_631.jpg" playsinline="" controls="" muted="" loop="" preload="none" autoplay="" src="/uploads/b/10433641-458365002498822034/final_v1_631.mp4"><source src="/uploads/b/10433641-458365002498822034/final_v1_631.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>`

If you know what I did wrong, could you explain in detail. I want to make sure you learn from this so I can handle it my on my own in the future.

Comment: I was able to get the mute button work on the desktop, but not on the phone. It can be a little glitchy on the desktop. So if anyone knows why it doesn't work on the phone, I would appreciate any advice. Also if there's a better way to get it to work on the desktop so it's not so glitchy, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error I was able to fix the problem. I'm not sure exactly what I did, but the video that was loading twice and I needed to prevent it from doing that.